# Logging around a SQL query while its executing in java

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, execution

I have a SQL query executing in java code.

the query takes a while to run.around 10 mins.

I want to add some repetitive logging while the query executes

something like "query is executing --- please wait"

how can this be achieved

Answer (score 1):

Future, Callable & ExecutorService helps to achieve this in a safe way.

You can run a query in separate thread using ExecutorService and use the Future object to hold the return value from thread. There is a method isDone() in Future interface and it returns boolean value true when task is completed.

Keep looping to print "query is executing --- please wait" until it returns true.

```
public class HelloWorldApp {

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException,
            ExecutionException {

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        System.out.println("submitted callable task to calculate factorial of 10");

        Future result10 = es.submit(new FactorialCalculator(10));
        System.out.println("Is job done: " + result10.isDone());
        System.out.println("\n");

        do {
            System.out.println("loading...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } while(!result10.isDone());

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Is job done:" + result10.isDone());

        long factorial10 = (long) result10.get();
        System.out.println("factorial of 10 is : " + factorial10);

        es.shutdown();
    }

}

class FactorialCalculator implements Callable<Long> {
    private int number;

    public FactorialCalculator(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        return factorial(number);
    }

    private long factorial(int n) throws InterruptedException {
        long result = 1;
        while (n != 0) {
            result = n * result;
            n = n - 1;
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```